# JAVA My Log File is only writing out the first variable?

Tags: java

Im pretty new to Java programming and im currently writing a java web app. Im currently trying to write out a log when a user creates a room, this is my code.

```
public class RoomLog{

private static RoomLog instance = new RoomLog();

private RoomLog() {

    try {

        fWriter = new FileWriter("RLog.txt", true);
        buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

    }

    catch(IOException ex) {

    }
}
    protected void finalize(){
    try {
        buffWriter.close();
        fWriter.close();

    } catch  (IOException ex) {

    }   
    }


    public static RoomLog getInstance(){
        return instance;

    }

    BufferedWriter buffWriter;
    FileWriter fWriter;
    static String newLine;


    public void Log(String msg){
        try {

            buffWriter.write(msg);
            buffWriter.write(newLine);
            buffWriter.flush();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("log exc");
        }
    }

}
```

That is my Room log code, and this is the code i have in my Servlet:

```
    RoomLog rLog = RoomLog.getInstance();
    rLog.Log(aRoom.toString());
```

Finally this is the code that is inside my Room class to try and get all of the attributes.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return String.format(getRoomName(), getRoomCode(), getRoomCapacity(),       getNumOfLights(), getBuildingCode());
}
```

But for some reason its only printing the roomName instead of all the other variables that is linked to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your use of `format` is not right.  The first argument should
be a format string, and then there are can be a variable number of argument (`vararg`)
that would supply values to position marked out in the format string.

So your method should instead be

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s %d, %s, %d %s"
        , getRoomName()
        , getRoomCode()
        , getRoomCapacity()
        , getNumOfLights()
        , getBuildingCode());
}
```

Note: I assume the return types of the five methods are these respectively:
String, int, String, int, String.

Please see this tutorial for more info:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 1):

The `String.format()` method takes, for its first argument, a format string.  You appear to have omitted this, making the method think that your `getRoomName()` argument IS the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String.format`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(getRoomName()).append(getRoomCode());
sb.append(getRoomCapacity()).append(getNumOfLights());
sb.append(getBuildingCode());
return sb.toString();
```